# Failing to locate landing page content (screenshots)

Tags: magento-1.9, landing-pages

I'm learning as i go with all of this. I have been using the inspect element tool to locate div classes / names / lines of css in order to edit the theme I am working with.

So far so good, apart from the landing page. I am trying to delete a div which contains a featured & new products display. When I open the inspector tool, I see this:

[image]

Although I can locate the files to edit almost everything else on the landing page (photo slider, text boxes, animated content) I can't locate where/how to edit any catalogue content which appears.

I have searched through these directories for the class name with no luck:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start off with, you might want to turn on "template path hints" (System > Configuration > Advanced, switch to your store from the dropdown in the lefthand corner, under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that allows you turn template path hints on or off).

Go to the frontend of your webshop and you'll see exactly which template you should be editing.

Comment: I have done this, located the files I should be editing. Strangely, I tried deleting both files that required editing, as I wanted them gone all together. Cleared the cache and when I check back at my webshop, they are still there, with the same template directory as before..

Comment: Ok, so I understand you tried deleting the actual template files from your theme directory (which is "accessshop"). What do you mean by the template files are still there? Depending on the files you tried to delete it is possible that Magento uses its fallback on these files from the base theme.

Comment: I replaced the files, deleted their contents and still am not seeing the desired result. If i simply delete the div.std in the inspect element tool, the entire grouping of elements i wish to be rid of is gone. I understand that Magento doesn't work in this way, but i'm trying to get the same result.